# Navigation Drawer issue

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, user-interface, navigation-drawer

I've been following the offical guide of google to create a simple Navigation Drawer. So far I 've changed my Main_Activity.xml layout to this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/> 
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Then on my MainActivity.java I added these:

```
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);

    // Creating an ArrayAdapter to add items to the listview mDrawerList
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), 
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mOptions);

    // Setting the adapter on mDrawerList
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I've also created the XML drawer_list_item with the following

```
 <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@android:id/text1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
     android:gravity="center_vertical"
     android:paddingLeft="16dp"
     android:paddingRight="16dp"
     android:textColor="#fff"
     android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
     android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"/>
```

Yet still I have nothing, not even an error. It just doesn't work, I think I am missing some simple, Thanks!

Comment: Please update the question and insert the xml layouts

Comment: Is there anything in mOptions?

Comment: private String[] mOptions={"Login","Search"};